# Hive query - Join or Subquery

Tags: join, subquery, hive

I'm looking for a performant query. I have got 2 Tables:

1. productviews(timecol TIMESTAMP,
   user_id STRING,
   product_id INT, location_city STRING)
2. productactions(timecol TIMESTAMP,
   user_id STRING,
   product_id INT, location_city STRING, action STRING)

action could be for example a shopping-cart insert.

I need to run a query that is grouped by location_city or product_id:

SELECT *, count(productviews), count(productactions), count(DISTINCT user_id) FROM xxx GROUP BY xxx

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: your problem is not clearly defined. You have 2 tables. If you taking value from both tables, in this you have to join both table.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. What exactly do you need to find?